# On the keepalived Master, how would I configure a notification when the Backup fails

Tags: keepalived

I want to run keepalived to manage an Active-Active pair of Linux servers.

How do I set up a notification that can run when the keepalived Backup fails, which will allow the Master to take over the Backup's load. And then a notification for when the Backup comes up again, so that the Master can relinquish its load?

The `notify`, `notify_master` and `notify_backup` notification hooks only work for *this* node's state transitions, not for those of the peer.

Or should I abandon using keepalived altogether and use something else?